# Novel set in medieval times: Sir John and two squires one of whom turns out to be a girl

Tags: identification-request

I have very vague memories of a children's/YA book that I borrowed from a library in England some time in the early 2000s. It was written in English and I don't think it was translated. I'm not sure if it was plain historical fiction or if there were fantasy elements, but I'd lean towards the former. It might be a standalone novel or part of a series, but certainly I didn't read any further if it was part of a series.

The viewpoint character was a boy who became assistant (squire?) to a fat knight named Sir John. There was also another boy serving in the same role; I think one of the boys was called Alan, but I'm not sure which one. Towards the end of the story, the second boy turns out to be secretly a girl in disguise (maybe there's some kind of bathroom scene where this is revealed?), and there's some kind of joke on "his"/her name: her real name is a feminine version of the name she'd assumed while posing as a boy.

The cover of the book was I think red or yellow in colour, and featured a cartoon-style drawing, showing Sir John as ridiculously fat. The book itself was quite thick, definitely a novel and not a novella or short story.

I know this isn't much to go on, and I can't really remember anything about the plot except the boy/girl reveal. Hopefully it'll be enough for someone with better memory or search skills than I to find the book.

Comment: Presumably not "Cue for Treason" or "Black Arrow"?

Comment: @mikado Nope, neither of those seems to be a children's book featuring squires to a knight named Sir John.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*The Knight and the Squire* by Terry Jones

Description taken from [amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1862050449):

> In a small village in 14th-century England, a bright young boy named
> Tom is restless. Tired of studying and digging ditches, he dreams of
> noble crusades in far-off lands. He decides that he must have his
> freedom and flees to the forest to elude pursuers. There he meets the
> terrifying Wolfman, who becomes an unexpected friend. Throughout his
> eventful journey, Tom encounters a colorful assortment of characters,
> but none more lively than Alan, who leads them both to France to fight
> for king and country. With its non-stop adventure and marvelous humor,
> readers will be turning the pages as quickly as they can to follow Tom
> and Alan through ambush and skirmish, battle and siege.

Booklist review of the sequel, available on [amazon.com](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1862054177) mentions Ann (AKA Alan).

Comment: Great, that's it! [Another Amazon review](https://www.amazon.com/Knight-Squire-Terry-Jones/dp/0140388044) mentions *"a mysterious new friend named Alan who has many different names with different people and makes his way to geat* [sic] *journeys with Alan and their knight Sir John"*, and the cover looks familiar too.